# Convert an SQL expression if it has a LENGTH function with SUBSELECT query to SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I know that in SQLite, we use the `LENGTH` function instead of `len`. But when I want to use the `LENGTH` function with a subquery like so:

```
select length(select name from tblNames where name=1)
```

I receive an error. Here is the Microsoft SQL version of the expression:

```
iif(len((select  BilgiAcik  from DigerBilg  where BilgTip=12  and BilgDgr=Cstr(Dr.Fr)))>0,( select  BilgiAcik  from DigerBilg  where BilgTip=12 and BilgDgr=Cstr(Dr.Fr)),Cstr(Dr.Fr))  as Fr,
```

I converted the above expression into SQLite as so:

```
(case length((select  BilgiAcik  from DigerBilg where BilgTip=12 and BilgDgr=CAST(Dr.Fr as TEXT))>0 ( select  BilgiAcik  from DigerBilg  where BilgTip=12 and BilgDgr=Cstr(Dr.Fr)) else CAST(Dr.Fr as TEXT) end) as Fr,
```

What I'm I doing wrong about? Can't I just use the `SUBSELECT` query with the `LRNGTH` function? Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to restructure your statement to be more similar to the following.

```
select length(name) from (select name from tblnames where name=1);
```

You can manage this a bit more easily by aliasing the subselects if you like.

```
select length(t.name) from (select name from tblnames where name=1) as t;
```